# Way to see the missing columns after calculating the minimum value in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Using pandas, I grouped a dataset by window number(winnum), latitude, and longitude.

The code is as follows.

```
final=[(win[j],ttdf[0][i],ttdf[1][i],(ttdf[2][i]-shift[j])**2) for i in range(len(ttdf))
      for j in range(len(ccdf))]

fidf=pd.DataFrame(final)

winnum=fidf[0]
latitue=fidf[1]
longitude=fidf[2]
difference=fidf[3]

titles = {0: 'winnum', 1: 'latitude', 2: 'longitude', 3: 'difference'}

fidf.rename(columns=titles, inplace=True)
```

Then I summed the difference value of each group to find the minimum value for each set of latitude and longitude.

```
grouped=fidf['difference'].groupby([fidf['winnum'],fidf['latitude'],fidf['longitude']])

s=grouped.sum()

lastdf=pd.DataFrame(s)

lastdf.min(level='winnum')
```

However, if I type the code above, I can only see two columns, which are 'winnum' and the minimum value of the sum of 'difference'.

What I want to do is to check the value of (latitude,longitude) which has the minimum value of 'difference sum' for each winnum.

Is there any way that I can see latitude and longitude columun here even after I calculate the minimum value of difference sum?

It would be a great help for me if you give me the answer. Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your groupby should result in Series with the sum of the differences. The winnum, latitude and longitude are still present in the index though.

Example:

```
fidf = pd.DataFrame({'winnum': [0,0,1,2],
                     'latitude': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                     'longitude': [3, 3, 4, 5],
                     'difference': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
grouped = fidf['difference'].groupby([fidf.winnum, 
                                      fidf.latitude, 
                                      fidf.longitude]).sum()
print(grouped.index.names)
# ['winnum', 'latitude', 'longitude']
```

You can get the index values for the minimum sum of differences with idxmin

```
winmum, lat, long = grouped.idxmin()
#(0, 1, 3)
```

If you want the row for each winnum with the minimum sum of difference, you can use the following lookup:

```
grouped.loc[grouped.groupby('winnum').idxmin()]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I think there was a missing point in my explanation. After typing the code I mentioned above, I type the code 'lastdf.min(level='winnum')' to find the minimum value of difference sum for each window number. My goal is to find the value of latitude and longitude that has the minimum value of difference sum 'for each 'winnum'. However, I can only see two columns, which are 'winnum' and 'difference' after i type 'lastdf.min(level='winnum')'. However, I also want to see the corresponding columns of latitude and longitude.

Comment: I added a line of code lastdf.min(level='winnum') and a image I've got after typing all these codes in my original post :)

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely a smarter way of keeping the value - however, why not simply add it back? Once you have `lastdf`:

```
lastdf = lastdf.reset_index()
lastdf.merge(fidf,how='left',on=['winnum','difference'])
```

This should just take the lat and lon of lines in fidf with the same winnum and difference and add it on.